# How to prevent importing duplicates to HSQL DB?

Tags: java, duplicates, hsqldb

I can't find any solution so I'm asking you guys for help.

How can I extend this statement so that a duplicate-check is done previously:

```
"INSERT INTO sample_table(str_col,num_col) VALUES('Ford', 100)"
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Use a SELECT first and then INSERT or UPDATE

Comment: Or better use a MERGE, which combines the two. Or create a unique constraint and handle the failure if the record existed.

Comment: Or use a [MERGE](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement) statement.

Comment: Could you guys give me an example? I'm not sure where to place the MERGE-Statement and with which parameters.

Comment: Would that MERGE statement be instead of the INSERT INTO statement?

Answer (score 0):

You create a UNIQUE index on the column(s) that need to contain unique values. If the values in str_col are supposed to be unique, a constraint on this column is needed.

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table ADD CONSTRAINT unique_c UNIQUE(str_col)
```

If the combinations of the two columns need to be unique, for example (Ford, 100), (Ford, 101) you should add

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table ADD CONSTRAINT unique_c UNIQUE(str_col, numb_col)
```

When you insert duplicated values into the table, an exception is thrown.

If you want to avoid the exception, use a MERGE statement to insert.

```
MERGE INTO sample_table USING VALUES('Ford', 100)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES('Ford', 100)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! First statement is working. With the second one I get an exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: 100.3 when I'm trying to insert "100.2"